# Sort array by second letter in swift 2.2

Tags: ios, swift, swift2

I want to sort the array by second letter of word. Some one has an idea? i will type a value and key, should return sorted list like this: 
array ["hello", "bye", "how", etc"]
Sorted: hello, how, etc, bye

```
static func sort(keyValue: [(key:String, value:String)]) -> [(key:String, value:String)] {

    let returnValue = keyValue( {$0 < $1}

    return returnValue
}
```

Comment: Please clarify your question a bit further

Comment: I tried to clarify more.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As an alternative to using `subStringFromIndex`—an alternative suitable specifically for the case of sorting by the *second* character (and in case of equality; following characters lexicographically) of each string—you can use the `dropFirst()` method of the `CharacterView` of each string:

```
let strings = ["hello", "bye", "how", "etc"]
let sortedStrings = strings
    .sort { String($0.characters.dropFirst()) < String($1.characters.dropFirst()) }

print(sortedStrings) // ["hello", "how", "etc", "bye"]
```

This is equivalent to the solution using `substringFromIndex` and `advancedBy`, with the upside that this will not yield a runtime exception in case the `strings` array contain an empty string (`""`) (although this can be remedied for the `advancedBy` solution by using `.advancedBy(1, limit: $0.endIndex)` and `.advancedBy(1, limit: $1.endIndex)` for the sorting keys, respectively).

---

Note also that lexicographical comparison will sort uppercase letters prior to any lowercase letter, such that `["hello", "bYe", "hOw", "etc"]` will sort into `["hOw", "bYe", "hello", "etc"]`. If you want case-insensitive sorting, you can apply the `.lowercaseString` property to the sorting keys:

```
let strings = ["hello", "bYe", "hOw", "etc"]
let sortedStrings = strings
    .sort { String($0.lowercaseString.characters.dropFirst()) <
        String($1.lowercaseString.characters.dropFirst()) }

print(sortedStrings) // ["hello", "hOw", "etc", "bYe"]
```

Comment: Thank you...! @dfri Implementing it now.

Comment: But when I tried to implement to `returnValue` didn't work. Should I take the string out ?

Comment: @dfri you can also use String method localizedCompare  instead of lowercaseString http://stackoverflow.com/a/30418608/2303865

Comment: @LeoDabus That's a good alternative, thanks! (Although not fully native; Foundation)

Comment: @JavierGomez I don't follow, could you add more details to your question? For example, a specific example of what expected output you want for a given input (note that your own sort functions seemingly takes an array of `(String, String)` _tuples_, rather than an array of strings).

Comment: Sure @dfri I have a user listing keys and value as it is enter the key/value it sorts by itself and shows sorted in a table. So, I have this:
`static func sort(keyValue: [(key:String, value:String)]) -> [(key:String, value:String)]
{        
        var val = keyValue
        var tempVal = val.map {"\($0) \($1)"}
        let sortedStrings = tempRetval.sort { $0.substringFromIndex($0.startIndex.advancedBy(1)) < $1.substringFromIndex($1.startIndex.advancedBy(1))  }       
 for valor in sortedStrings
        {
            //I guess need to fill dictionary
        }
        return retval
    }`

Comment: Actually I will respond myself. I just changed like this:
`let sorted = retval.sort { $0.0.substringFromIndex($0.key.startIndex.advancedBy(1)) < $1.key.substringFromIndex($1.key.startIndex.advancedBy(1)) }` 
I sorted directly the dictionary.

Answer (score 3):

You can use `substringFromIndex` with the standard `sort` or `sortInPlace` functions:

```
let strings = ["hello", "bye", "how", "etc"]
let sortedStrings = strings.sort { $0.substringFromIndex($0.startIndex.advancedBy(1)) < $1.substringFromIndex($1.startIndex.advancedBy(1)) }
```

Comment: Possibly worth mentioning that it could be appropriate to use `advancedBy(_:limit:)` (e.g. `.advancedBy(1, limit: $0.endIndex)` for first key above) rather than `advancedBy(_:)` to safe-guard against empty strings in the `strings` array.